# Copying array in C and getting rid of the garbage in char array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to copy a big string with an url like `"https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png"` into a smaller array with only the url and the NULL terminator `https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png\0`, but I'm getting garbage behind the array.

The problem should be here:

```
pos2 = 0;
while (found == 0)
{
    c = fgetc (fp); // get char from file
    link[pos2] = c;
    if (link[pos2-1] == 'g' && link[pos2] == '\"') // png and jpg files
    {
    found = 1;
    }
    ++pos2;
}
--pos2;
found = 0;
char link2[pos2];
for (j = 1; j < pos2; ++j)
{
    link2[j-1] = link[j];
}
link2[j] = '\0';
//sprintf(cmd, "wget -O /home/arturo/Dropbox/Digital_Renders/%d \'%s\'", ++num, link2);
//system(cmd);
printf("%s\n", link2);// checking
sleep(1);
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // for using system calls
#include <unistd.h> // for sleep

int main ()
{
    char  body[] = "forum-post-body-content", notes[] = "p-comment-notes", img[] = "img src=", link[200], cmd[200]={0}, file[10];
    int c, pos = 0, pos2 = 0, fin = 0, i, j, num = 0, found = 0;
    FILE *fp;

    for (i = 1; i < 500; ++i)
    {
        sprintf(cmd,"wget -O page%d.txt 'http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/creativity/artwork/340782-official-digital-rendering-thread?page=%d'",i,i);
        system(cmd);
        sprintf(file, "page%d.txt", i);
        fp = fopen (file, "r");
        while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        {
            if (body[pos] == c)
            {
                if (pos == 22)
                {
                    pos = 0;
                    while (fin == 0)
                    {
                        c = fgetc (fp);
                        if (feof (fp))
                            break;
                        if (notes[pos] == c)
                        {
                            if (pos == 14)
                            {
                                fin = 1;
                                pos = -1;
                            }
                            ++pos;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(pos > 0)
                                pos = 0;
                        }
                        if (img[pos2] == c)
                        {
                            if (pos2 == 7)
                            {
                                pos2 = 0;
                                while (found == 0)
                                {
                                    c = fgetc (fp); // get char from file
                                    link[pos2] = c;
                                    if (pos2 > 0)
                                    {
                                        if(link[pos2-1] == 'g' && link[pos2] == '\"')
                                        {
                                        found = 1;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ++pos2;
                                }
                                --pos2;
                                found = 0;
                                char link2[pos2];
                                for (j = 1; j < pos2; ++j)
                                {
                                    link2[j - 1] = link[j];
                                }
                                link2[j - 1] = '\0';
                                //sprintf(cmd, "wget -O /home/arturo/Dropbox/Digital_Renders/%d \'%s\'", ++num, link2);
                                //system(cmd);
                                printf("%s\n", link2);// checking
                                sleep(1);
                                pos2 = -1;
                            }
                            ++pos2;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(pos2 > 0)
                                pos2 = 0;
                        }
                    }
                fin = 0;
                }
                ++pos;
            }
            else
                pos = 0;
        }
        // closing file
        fclose (fp);
        if (remove (file))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't remove file\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: memset the array to all zeroes before working with it.

Comment: you start with `pos2 = 0` and access `link[pos2-1]`, that's out of bounds and so undefined behaviour.

Comment: In idiomatic C, your loop that starts `while (1) { c = fgetc (fp); if (feof (fp)) break;` would be written `while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {`.  However, what you've written is sound enough, though using `feof()` is a habit to break now, rather than later.

Comment: tldr : Try to avoid writing functions that are more than 50 lines, especially in C, that will be better for you, now and in the future and ofc for everybody looking to your code. Splitting "this" thing will improve you refactor skill :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your immediate problem seems to be because of this line :

```
link2[j] = '\0';
```

which should be :

```
link2[j-1] = '\0';
```

(consistent with the indexing inside the loop).

Additionally, as @mch pointed out in a comment, accessing `link[pos2-1]` for the first iteration of the while loop will access an item out of bounds of the array.

Quickly scanning the rest of the code, there seem to be several more issues lurking, so you might want to take a very close look at the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

Given the declaration:

```
char cmd[50];
```

this line is bad:

```
sprintf(cmd,"wget -O page%d.txt 'http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/creativity/artwork/340782-official-digital-rendering-thread?page=%d'",i,i);
```

You are trying to pack over 120 characters into a 50 byte buffer; this won't work reliably.

Answer (score 0):

You have another occurrence of reading out of bounds here:

```
pos2 = 0;           /* pos2 = 0 */
while (found == 0)
{
    c = fgetc (fp);
    link[pos2] = c;
    if (link[pos2-1] == 'g' && link[pos2] == '\"')  /* reading pos2 - 1  (bad) */
```

Pay particular attention to all array indexes. You will rarely want to shift indexes (i.e. `i-1`, etc.) if you do, your must **validate** your index ranges do not attempt to **read out-of-bounds**.